# Base64 encoding using Span<T> in dotnetcore 2.1

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am playing with the new `Span<T>` and I am trying to understand how it works. My target is to rework the following function to use ReadOnlySpan:

```
public static string Base64Encode(this string plainText)
{
    var plainTextBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
    return System.Convert.ToBase64String(plainTextBytes);
}
```

What I have so far is:

```
public static unsafe ReadOnlySpan<char> Base64Encode(this ReadOnlySpan<char> s)
{
    int byteCount = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(s);
    IntPtr unmanagedPointer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(byteCount);

    Span<byte> plainTextBytes = new Span<byte>((void*)unmanagedPointer, byteCount);
    System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s, plainTextBytes);
    return System.Convert.ToBase64String(plainTextBytes).AsSpan();
}
```

1. What is the better way to achieve the goal?
2. What should be changed to avoid memory leak?

Ideally the final result should look like:

```
public static unsafe ReadOnlySpan<char> Base64Encode(this ReadOnlySpan<char> s)
{
    //code without allocations
}
```

---

**EDIT**: Without returning `Span<T>`

```
public static unsafe string Base64Encode(this ReadOnlySpan<char> s)
{
    int byteCount = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(s);
    IntPtr unmanagedPointer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(byteCount);

    Span<byte> plainTextBytes = new Span<byte>((void*)unmanagedPointer, byteCount);
    System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s, plainTextBytes);
    return System.Convert.ToBase64String(plainTextBytes);
}
```

Comment: As `Span` is basically a view into a container of data existing on it's own, returning a Span from your function does not really make sense. It would only make sense if there was a globally available array of base64 data you'd refer to.

Comment: OK, so the function will be something like the code which I have added in the question. 10x

Comment: Size matters not. `</Yoda>`. You create the new array yourself, every time. There is no point in using a span into a dynamically created array. If your calling code wants to use spans later on that array... fine.

Comment: The updated function makes no sense either. The revised function is a shambling horror that pointlessly allocates new unmanaged memory to hold the input, which is exactly the thing `Span` was designed to avoid. There is no meaningful way to use `Span` here -- you can cut down on allocations if it's an issue, but that involves rewriting `ToBase64String` to directly use a `UTF8Encoder`, rather than eating a `byte[]`. `Span` and `ReadOnlySpan` serve specific goals; you should not rewrite any old function using strings or byte arrays to suddenly use `Span`.

Comment: Take a look at [`Base64.EncodeToUtf8`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Memory/src/System/Buffers/Text/Base64Encoder.cs), which takes an input span of bytes and writes UTF-8 encoded Base64 directly to an output span. That's basically how you'd write your proposed `Base64Encode` method. Note that it takes a `ReadOnlySpan<byte>` for its input and a `Span<byte>` for its output. It does not allocate anything, as it relies on the calling code to supply the buffers; it only has to take care of tracking the number of bytes read/written.